# Twitter Bootstrap 3: Aligning columns to container content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know how to solve this issue using CSS that overrides Bootstrap's compiled CSS, but it seems to me this alignment issue is such a common use case that I must have misunderstood  how to use the Bootstrap framework. (First time with Bootstrap.)

**Case:** The columns in container B ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ELJH/2/)) do not align with the content in container A, because Bootstrap generates a 15px left/right padding to each column.

```
<section class="container A">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>Lorem</p>
</section>

<section class="container B">

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Hiya!</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Hiya!</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Hiya!</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Hiya!</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

</section>
```

**Question:** Is there a way I can make the column content align to the container A content, by changing the HTML only, without using any CSS?

**Setup:** I'm required to use Twitter bootstrap 3.0.0 for the above.

**OT:** As you see this is my first post on SO, I'm grateful for any advice on how to improve this question and its markup.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Your question is great. Not too much code, link to JS Fiddle is really helpful. I believe you will receive answer in no time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you used two `containers`, I updated your fiddle with two `rows` instead and a `div` with class `col-md-12` to take up the whole width of the screen in the first row, check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/3ELJH/3/